# afpd[]: PAM audit_log_acct_message() failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: ldap, pam, pam-ldap, afp

Im trying to debug this error in the /var/log/auth but I dont know where to look at.

```
Jul 27 06:44:30 server afpd[6463]: PAM audit_log_acct_message() failed: Operation not permitted
```

The syslog seems fine:

```
Jul 27 06:43:39 server afpd[6463]: AFP3.3 Login by demouser
Jul 27 06:44:30 server afpd[6463]: AFP logout by demouser
Jul 27 06:44:30 server afpd[6463]: AFP statistics: 42948.28 KB read, 76711.14 KB written
Jul 27 06:44:30 server afpd[6463]: done
```

The error seems to happen with the AFP session is closing. I havent notice any issue though on login or on file transfer. It worths to mention that the authentication is going through an LDAP server. Any ideas where to identify the issue?